# Naming file to save when php export to xls

Tags: php, excel, naming-conventions

My code kinda weird, i don't know what would be the problem of my code.. here's my code.

```
$project_name = $_POST['project_name'];//example the retrieved data is Testing Project
$quote_id = $_POST['quote_id'];//example the retrieved data is 34425
$date = date("M/d/y");
$as_agent = $_POST['as_agent'];//example the retrieved data is John Doe

$name_for_project = $project_name.' '.$quote_id.' '.$date.' '.$as_agent;


header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename='".$name_for_project.".xls'");
ob_start();

//The rest of the code is Workbook
echo"
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <?mso-application progid='Excel.Sheet'?>
    <Workbook
xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'
xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'
xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'
xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'
xmlns:html='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
<DocumentProperties xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'>
    <Version>11.8036</Version>
</DocumentProperties>
<ExcelWorkbook xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'>
    <WindowHeight>6795</WindowHeight>
    <WindowWidth>8460</WindowWidth>
    <WindowTopX>120</WindowTopX>
    <WindowTopY>15</WindowTopY>
    <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
    <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
</ExcelWorkbook>";

    //so on and so fort...
```

When this code runs it only capture the $project_name value.. Please Help me... Thank you..

Comment: You may need to show us your full code or what these variables are `$project_name` `$quote_id` `$date` `$as_agent` - there might be something in `date` or other variable causing this.

Comment: Are we magically supposed to know what the other variables values are? Show us how you declare/set them!

Comment: But from what I could test, a space is produced between each variable which will produce `project quote_id date as_agent` - you may not have declared them (`$quote_id $date $as_agent`) after `$project_name`

Comment: You may even want to use an underscore instead of a space, such as `$name_for_project = $project_name.'_'.$quote_id.'_'.$date.'_'.$as_agent;`

Comment: all of the variables inside $name_for_project are all POST data's..

Comment: Actually i tried all of them $project_name,$quote_id,$date, $as_agent into name.. ex. header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=$project_name.xls"); and all of them are good.. but when i am going to concat all of the variable.. the first variable is the only data retrieved.. sorry for bad english.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line `header("...` will prompt to save a file with apostrophes to the beginning and end of the file.

**Example**: `'project_quote_id_2013-08-31_as_agent.xls'`

```
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename='".$name_for_project.".xls'");
```

### which should be changed to:

```
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=".$name_for_project.".xls");
```

---

The code below will produce/echo a saveable file called: `project_quote_id_2013-08-31_as_agent.xls` (as of today's date for testing).

If, and as Aiden stated in his answer, you are using slashes as your seperator for your `$date` variable, you will encounter problems.

Try to avoid using spaces for seperators, use hyphens and/or underscores to seperate your values.

For example, this will save to prompt to a file with some dummy content.

```
<?php  

$date = gmdate('Y-m-d', time() - 3600 * $hours);
$project_name = "project";
$quote_id = "quote_id";
$as_agent = "as_agent";
$name_for_project = $project_name.'_'.$quote_id.'_'.$date.'_'.$as_agent;

$file = $name_for_project.".xls";

// start buffering  
ob_start();  
// sample dynamically generated data  
echo '<table border="1"> ';  
echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>';  
for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) { echo "<tr><td>Name$i</td><td>".($i+1)."</td></tr>";  
}  
echo '</table>';  
$content = ob_get_contents();  
ob_end_clean();  
header("Expires: 0");  
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");  
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");  
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);  
header("Pragma: no-cache");  
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset:UTF-8");  
header('Content-length: '.strlen($content));  
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));  
// output all contents  
echo $content;  
exit;
?>
```

will produce a  file called: `project_quote_id_2013-08-31_as_agent.xls` (as of today's testing date) and will prompt the user to save it under that name.

> **The rest of the code that is to insert the actual content, will need to be inserted accordingly, because there was nothing else posted in regards to variables or text associated with the question/code.**

Comment: I tried this code header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=".$name_for_project.".xls");

Comment: but it seems it is not working.. then if your going to echo the $name_for_project it will output correctly.. but when it will used as a name for file.. it didn't work

Comment: spaces effect naming the file i use str_replace function Thank you very much.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Do any of your other variables contain invalid characters for a file name? E.g. If you declared your $date as 30/08/2013 then php will not concatenate your variables past the invalid character.

Comment: You stand at being 50% right, and 50% wrong. We don't know what's in the rest of the OP's code, good luck in tonight's "lottery" ;-)

Comment: i tried to declare the date as $date = date("M-d-y"); but it didn't work.. in the $name_for_project = $project_name.' '.$quote_id.' '.$date.' '.$as_agent; the only retrieved data is the first one which is $project_name but the rest concated is not retrieved or not shown in the filename created..

Answer (score 0):

Spaces affect in naming filename. what i do is transform my code into.

```
$project_name = $_POST['project_name'];//example the retrieved data is Testing Project    
$quote_id = $_POST['quote_id'];//example the retrieved data is 34425
$date = date("M/d/y");
$as_agent = $_POST['as_agent'];//example the retrieved data is John Doe
$proj_name = str_replace(' ', '', $project_name);
$as_agent = str_replace(' ', '', $as_agent);

$name_for_project = $proj_name."-".$quote_id."-".$date."-".$as_agent; 


header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=$name_for_project.xls");
```

Thanks to @Fred -ii-